# C++ fraction class *Updated

Tags: c++, object-oriented, rational-numbers

This fraction class is a project I'm working on for fun. I want it to the best it can be. Please let me know if I'm following best procedures or if I'm missing something.

**Update
So, I took the advice from the answers I received and tried to improve my code. I'm curious, can I improve more? Am I missing anything one would consider important in such an object, maybe an overload of operator++ ? This post has been updated with the improved fraction class code below the original, "stdafx.h" remains unchanged.

The "stdafx.h" file below

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "fraction.h"
#include <cmath>
```

The "fraction.h" file below.

```
#pragma once

class fraction
{
    private:
        unsigned int numerator;
        unsigned int denominator;
        char fraction_symbol;
        bool is_reduced;
        bool is_neg;

    public:
        fraction();
        fraction(int, int);
        fraction(unsigned int);
        fraction(int);
        fraction(float);
        fraction(double);
        fraction reduce();
        int unsigned get_numerator();
        int unsigned get_denominator();
        void set_numerator(int);
        void set_denominator(int);
        void set_neg();
        bool check_neg();
        friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream & is, fraction & p);
        friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream & os, fraction & p); 
        friend fraction operator+ (fraction, fraction);
        friend fraction operator- (fraction, fraction);
        friend fraction operator* (fraction, fraction);
        friend fraction operator/ (fraction, fraction);
        friend bool operator== (fraction, fraction);
        friend bool operator!= (fraction, fraction);
        friend bool operator<= (fraction, fraction);
        friend bool operator>= (fraction, fraction);
        friend bool operator< (fraction, fraction);
        friend bool operator> (fraction, fraction);
};
```

The "fraction.cpp" file below.

```
 #include "stdafx.h"

 static int gcd(int, int);      /// barrowed function see definition.
 static void input_check(std::string&);


fraction::fraction()
{
    fraction_symbol = '/';
    is_reduced = false;
    is_neg = false;
    numerator = 1;
    denominator = 1;
}

fraction::fraction(int numer,int denom)
{
    if (denom == 0)
    {
         while (std::cout << "Illegal! Division by 0!" << std::endl << 
         "Please 
         enter a new denominator: " && !(std::cin >> denom) || (denom == 0))
         {
             std::cin.clear();
             std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), 
             '\n');
             std::cout << "Invalid entry, please try again." << std::endl;
        }
    }
    if ((numer < 0) && (denom < 0))
    {
        numer *= -1;
        denom *= -1;
    }
    if (numer < 0 )
    {
        is_neg = true;
        numer *= -1;
    }
    if (denom < 0)
    {
        is_neg = true;
        denom *= -1;
    }
    numerator = numer;
    denominator = denom;
    fraction_symbol = '/';
}

fraction::fraction(unsigned int temp)
{
    numerator = temp;
    denominator = temp;
    is_neg = false;
    reduce();
}

fraction::fraction( int temp)
{
    if (temp < 0)
    {
        is_neg = true;
        temp *= -1;
    }
    else
    {
        is_neg = false;
    }
    numerator = temp;
    denominator = temp;
    reduce();
}

int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    if (a == 0)
    {
        return b;
    }
    else if (b == 0)
    {   
        return a;
    }
    if (a < b)
    {           
        return gcd(a, b % a);
    }
    else
    {   
        return gcd(b, a % b);
    }
}


fraction::fraction(float temp)
{
    if (temp < 0)
    {
        is_neg = true;
        temp *= -1;
    }
    else
    {
        is_neg = false;
    }
    double integral = std::floor(temp);                                                    
    ///Euclidean algorithm , from here to
    double frac = temp - integral;
    //possible tweak could be done here, This is the accuracy below.                           
    const unsigned int precision = 10000;               
    unsigned int gcd_ = unsigned int(gcd(int(round(frac * precision)), 
    int(precision)));   
    /* stackoverflow.com, user: qbt937, url: 
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643695/converting-decimal-to-
    fraction-c */
    denominator = precision / gcd_;
    numerator = unsigned int(round(frac * precision) / gcd_);                              
    //here. credit for code block in middle...
    reduce();
    numerator += unsigned int((integral*denominator));
    reduce();
}

fraction::fraction(double temp)
{
    if (temp < 0)
    {
        is_neg = true;
        temp *= -1;
    }
    else
    {
        is_neg = false;
    }
    double integral = std::floor(temp);                                                    
    ///Euclidean algorithm , from here to
    double frac = temp - integral;
    const unsigned int precision = 10000;                                                  
    //possible tweak could be done here, This is the accuracy.
    unsigned int gcd_ = unsigned int(gcd(int(round(frac * precision)), 
    int(precision)));   
    /* stackoverflow.com, user: qbt937, url: 
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643695/converting-decimal-to-
    fraction-c */
    denominator = precision / gcd_;
    numerator = unsigned int(round(frac * precision) / gcd_);                              
    //here. credit for code block in middle...
    reduce();
    numerator += unsigned int((integral*denominator));
    reduce();
}

fraction fraction::reduce()
{
    for (long int i = (denominator * numerator);i > 1; i--)
    {
        if ((denominator % i == 0) && ((numerator % i) == 0))
        {
            is_reduced = true;
            numerator /= i;
            denominator /= i;
        }
    }
    if (is_reduced == false)
    {
        std::cout << "This fraction could not be reduced." << std::endl;
    }
    return *this;
}

unsigned int fraction::get_numerator()
{
    return numerator;
}

unsigned int fraction::get_denominator() 
{
    return denominator;
}

void fraction::set_numerator(int temp)
{
    if (temp < 0)
    {
        set_neg();
        temp *= -1;
    }
    else
    {
        numerator = temp;
    }  

}

void fraction::set_denominator(int temp)
{
    if (temp == 0)
    {
        while (std::cout << "Illegal! Division by 0!" << std::endl << 
        "Please enter a new denominator: " && !(std::cin >> temp) || (temp 
        == 0))   ///edit here to work in visual studios atleast....
            {
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), 
                '\n');
                std::cout << "Invalid entry, please try again." << 
                std::endl;
            }
    }
    if (temp < 0)
    {
        set_neg();
        temp *= -1;
        denominator = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        denominator = temp;
    }
}

std::istream& operator >> (std::istream & is, fraction & p)
{
    std::string temp_input;
    if (char(is.peek()) == '\n')
    {
        is.ignore();
    }
    std::getline(is, temp_input);
    input_check(temp_input);
    std::istringstream temp_string(temp_input);
    char holder = ' ';
    if (temp_input[0] == '-')
    {
        p.is_neg = true;
        temp_string >> holder >> p.numerator >> holder >> p.denominator;
    }
    else
    {
        temp_string >> p.numerator >> holder >> p.denominator;
    }
    return is;
}

std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream & os, fraction & p)
{
    if (p.is_neg == true)
    {
        os << "-" << p.numerator << "/" << p.denominator << std::flush;
        return os;
    }
    else
    {
        os << p.numerator << "/" << p.denominator << std::flush;
        return os;
    }
}


void input_check(std::string &temp_input)
{
    bool error = false;
    bool is_negative = false;
    int frac_symb_index = -1;   
    if (temp_input.length() < 3)
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid entry, please try again: " << std::flush;
        if (char(std::cin.peek()) == '\n')
        {
            std::cin.ignore();
        }
        std::getline(std::cin, temp_input);
        input_check(temp_input);
    }
    switch (temp_input[0])
    {
        case '-':
            is_negative = true;
            if (temp_input[1] == '/')
            {
                error = true;
            }
            break;
        case '0':
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7': 
        case '8':
        case '9':
            break;

        default:
            error = true;
            break;
    }
    int i;
    if (is_negative == true)
    {
        i = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        i = 0;
    }
    for (; i < int(temp_input.length() - 1); i++)
    {
        switch (temp_input[i])
        {
            case '0':
            case '1':
            case '2':
            case '3':
            case '4':
            case '5':
            case '6':   
            case '7':
            case '8':
            case '9':   
                break;
            case '/':
                frac_symb_index = i;
                break;  

            default:
                error = true;
                break;
        }
    }
    if (is_negative == true)
    {
        i = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        i = 0;
    }
    for(; i < frac_symb_index; i++)
    {
        switch (temp_input[i])
        {
            case '0':
            case '1':
            case '2':
            case '3':
            case '4':
            case '5':
            case '6':
            case '7':
            case '8':
            case '9':
                break; 

            default:
                error = true;
                break;
        }
    }
    for (int j = (temp_input.length()-1); frac_symb_index < j; j--)
    {
        switch (temp_input[j])
        {
            case '0':
            case '1':
            case '2':
            case '3':
            case '4':
            case '5':
            case '6':
            case '7':
            case '8':
            case '9':
                break; 

            default:
                error = true;
                break;
        }
    }
    if (error == true)
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid entry, please try again: " << std::flush;
        if (char(std::cin.peek()) == '\n')
        {
            std::cin.ignore();
        }
        std::getline(std::cin, temp_input);
        input_check(temp_input);
    }
}

fraction operator+ (fraction one, fraction two)  
{
    int added_num = 0;
    int common_denom = 0;
    bool is_it_neg = false;
    if (one.is_neg == false && two.is_neg == false)
    {
        added_num = ((one.get_numerator() * two.get_denominator()) + 
        (two.get_numerator() * one.get_denominator()));
        common_denom = (one.get_denominator() * two.get_denominator());
    }
    if (one.is_neg == true && two.is_neg == true )
    {
        added_num = ((one.get_numerator() * two.get_denominator()) + 
        (two.get_numerator() * one.get_denominator()));
        common_denom = (one.get_denominator() * two.get_denominator());
        is_it_neg = true;
    }
    if (one.is_neg == true && two.is_neg == false)
    {
        added_num = ((one.get_numerator() * two.get_denominator()) - 
        (two.get_numerator() * one.get_denominator()));
        common_denom = (one.get_denominator() * two.get_denominator());
        if (added_num > 0)
        {
            is_it_neg = true;
        }
    }
    if (one.is_neg == false && two.is_neg == true)
    {
        added_num = ((one.get_numerator() * two.get_denominator()) - 
        (two.get_numerator() * one.get_denominator()));
        common_denom = (one.get_denominator() * two.get_denominator());
        if (added_num < 0)
        {
            added_num *= -1;
            is_it_neg = true;
        }
    }
    fraction result(added_num,common_denom);
    if (is_it_neg == true)
    {
        result.set_neg();
    }
    result.reduce();
    return result;
}

void fraction::set_neg()
{
    if (is_neg == true)
    {
        is_neg = false;
    }
    else
    {
        is_neg = true;
    }
}

bool fraction::check_neg()
{
    if (is_neg == true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

fraction operator- (fraction one, fraction two)
{
    int subed_num = 0;
    int common_denom = 0;
    bool is_it_neg = false;
    if (one.is_neg == false && two.is_neg == false)
    {
        subed_num = ((one.get_numerator() * two.get_denominator()) - 
        (two.get_numerator() * one.get_denominator()));
        common_denom = (one.get_denominator() * two.get_denominator());
        if (subed_num < 0)
        {
            subed_num *= -1;
            is_it_neg = true;
        }
    }
    if (one.is_neg == true && two.is_neg == true)
    {
        subed_num = (((one.get_numerator() * -1) * two.get_denominator()) + 
        (two.get_numerator() * one.get_denominator()));
        common_denom = (one.get_denominator() * two.get_denominator());
        if (subed_num < 0)
        {
            subed_num *= -1;
            is_it_neg = true;
        }
    }
    if (one.is_neg == true && two.is_neg == false)
    {
        subed_num = ((one.get_numerator() * two.get_denominator()) + 
        (two.get_numerator() * one.get_denominator()));
        common_denom = (one.get_denominator() * two.get_denominator());
        is_it_neg = true;
    }
    if (one.is_neg == false && two.is_neg == true)
    {
        subed_num = ((one.get_numerator() * two.get_denominator()) + 
        (two.get_numerator() * one.get_denominator()));
        common_denom = (one.get_denominator() * two.get_denominator());
    }
    char temp = '+';
    if (is_it_neg == true)
    {
        temp = '-';
    }
    fraction result(subed_num, common_denom);
    if (is_it_neg == true)
    {
        result.set_neg();
    }
    result.reduce();
    return result;
}

fraction operator* (fraction a, fraction b)
{
    fraction result((a.get_numerator() * b.get_numerator()),
    (a.get_denominator() * b.get_denominator()));
    if (a.check_neg() || b.check_neg())
    {
        result.set_neg();
    }
    result.reduce();
    return result;
}

fraction operator/ (fraction a, fraction b)
{
    fraction result((a.get_numerator() * b.get_denominator()), 
    (a.get_denominator() * b.get_numerator()));
    if (a.check_neg() || b.check_neg())
    {
        result.set_neg();
    }
    result.reduce();
    return result;
}

bool operator== (fraction a, fraction b)
{
    double c = (double(a.get_numerator()) / double(a.get_denominator()));
    double d = (double(b.get_numerator()) / double(b.get_denominator()));
    if (a.check_neg())
    {
        c *= -1;
    }
    if (b.check_neg())
    {
        d *= -1;
    }
    if (c == d)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool operator!= (fraction a, fraction b)
{
    double x = (double(a.get_numerator() )/ double(a.get_denominator()));
    double y = (double(b.get_numerator()) / double(b.get_denominator()));
    if (a.check_neg())
    {
        x *= -1;
    }
    if (b.check_neg())
    {
        y *= -1;
    }
    if (x != y)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool operator<= (fraction a, fraction b)
{
    double e = (double(a.get_numerator()) / double(a.get_denominator()));
    double f = (double(b.get_numerator()) / double(b.get_denominator()));
    if (a.check_neg())
    {
        e *= -1;
    }
    if (b.check_neg())
    {
        f *= -1;
    }
    if (e <= f)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool operator>= (fraction a, fraction b)
{
    double g = (double(a.get_numerator()) / double(a.get_denominator()));
    double h = (double(b.get_numerator()) / double(b.get_denominator()));
    if (a.check_neg())
    {
        g *= -1;
    }
    if (b.check_neg())
    {
        h *= -1;
    }
    if (g >= h)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool operator< (fraction a, fraction b) 
{   
    double i = (double(a.get_numerator()) / double(a.get_denominator()));
    double j = (double(b.get_numerator()) / double(b.get_denominator()));
    if (a.check_neg())
    {
        i *= -1;
    }
    if (b.check_neg())
    {
        j *= -1;
    }
    if (i < j)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool operator> (fraction a, fraction b)
{
    double k = (double(a.get_numerator()) / double(a.get_denominator()));
    double l = (double(b.get_numerator()) / double(b.get_denominator()));
    if (a.check_neg())
    {
        k *= -1;
    }
    if (b.check_neg())
    {
        l *= -1;
    }
    if (k > l)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**updated code below
"fraction.h"

```
#pragma once

class fraction
{
    private:
        unsigned int numerator;       
        unsigned int denominator;     
        bool is_reduced;
        bool is_neg;
        void toggle_neg();
        void reduce();

    public:
        fraction();
        fraction(int, int);
        fraction(unsigned int);
        fraction(int);
        fraction(float);
        fraction(double);
        friend std::istream &operator >> (std::istream &is, fraction &p);
        friend std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &os, fraction &p); 
        int& operator=(fraction const &);
        fraction& operator += (fraction const &);   
        friend fraction operator + (fraction const&, fraction const&);   
        fraction& operator -= (fraction const &);
        friend fraction operator - (fraction, fraction);
        fraction& operator *= (fraction const &);
        friend fraction operator * (fraction, fraction);
        fraction& operator /= (fraction const & two);
        friend fraction operator / (fraction, fraction);
        bool operator == (fraction const&) const;
        bool operator != (fraction const&) const;
        bool operator < (fraction const &) const;
        bool operator > (fraction const &) const;
        bool operator <= (fraction const &) const;
        bool operator >= (fraction const &) const;
};
```

**updated code below
"fraction.cpp"

```
#include "stdafx.h"


static int gcd(int, int);              /// barrowed function see definition.
static void input_check(std::string&);


int gcd(int a, int b)     
{
    if (a == 0)
    {
        return b;
    }
    else if (b == 0)
    {
         return a;
    }
    if (a < b)
    {
        return gcd(a, b % a);
    }
    else
    {
        return gcd(b, a % b);
    }
}              

void input_check(std::string &temp_input)
{
    bool error = false;
    bool is_negative = false;
    int frac_symb_index = -1;
    if (temp_input.length() < 3)
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid entry, please try again: ";
        if (char(std::cin.peek()) == '\n')
        {
            std::cin.ignore();
        }
        std::getline(std::cin, temp_input);
        input_check(temp_input);
    }
    switch (temp_input[0])
    {
        case '-':
            is_negative = true;
            if (temp_input[1] == '/')
            {
                error = true;
            }
            break;  
        case '0':
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9':
            break;

        default:
            error = true;
            break;
    }
    int i;
    if (is_negative)
    {
        i = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        i = 0;
    }
    for (; i < int(temp_input.length() - 1); i++)
    {
        switch (temp_input[i])
        {
            case '0':
            case '1':
            case '2':
            case '3':
            case '4':
            case '5':
            case '6':
            case '7':
            case '8':
            case '9':
                break;
            case '/':
                frac_symb_index = i;
                break;

            default:
                error = true;
                break;
        }
    }
    if (is_negative)
    {
        i = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        i = 0;
    }
    for (; i < frac_symb_index; i++)
    {
        switch (temp_input[i])
        {
            case '0':
            case '1':
            case '2':
            case '3':
            case '4':
            case '5':
            case '6':
            case '7':
            case '8':
            case '9':
                break;  

            default:
                error = true;
                break;
        }
    }
    for (int j = (temp_input.length() - 1); frac_symb_index < j; j--)
    {
        switch (temp_input[j])
        {
            case '0':
            case '1':
            case '2':
            case '3':
            case '4':
            case '5':
            case '6':
            case '7':
            case '8':
            case '9':
                break; 

            default:
                error = true;
                break;
        }
    }
    if (error)
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid entry, please try again: ";
        if (char(std::cin.peek()) == '\n')
        {
            std::cin.ignore();
        }
        std::getline(std::cin, temp_input);
        input_check(temp_input);}
}

void fraction::toggle_neg()
{
    (is_neg) ? is_neg = false : is_neg = true;
}

void fraction::reduce()
{
    int max = 0;
    (this->numerator >= this->denominator) ? max = numerator : max = 
    denominator;
    for (long int i = max; i > 1; i--)
    {
        if ((this->denominator % i == 0) && ((this->numerator % i) == 0))
        {
            this->is_reduced = true;
            this->numerator /= i;
            this->denominator /= i;
        }
    }
}

fraction::fraction()
    :is_reduced(false)
    , is_neg(false)
    , numerator(0)
    , denominator(0)
{

}

fraction::fraction(int numer, int denom)
    :fraction()
{
    if (denom == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Illegal division by zero."///error handling on the way
    }
    if ((numer < 0) && (denom < 0))
    {
        numer *= -1;
        denom *= -1;
    }
    if (numer < 0 )
    {
        is_neg = true;
        numer *= -1;
    }
    if (denom < 0)
    {
        is_neg = true;
        denom *= -1;
    }
    this->numerator = numer;
    this->denominator = denom;  
    this->reduce();
}

fraction::fraction(unsigned int temp)
    :fraction()
{
    numerator = temp;
    denominator = 1;
}

fraction::fraction(int temp)
    :fraction()
{
    if (temp < 0)
    {
        is_neg = true;
        temp *= -1;
    }
    else
    {
        is_neg = false;
    }
    numerator = temp;
    denominator = temp;
    reduce();
}

fraction::fraction(float temp)
{
    if (temp < 0)
    {
        is_neg = true;
        temp *= -1;
    }
    else
    {
        is_neg = false;
    }
    double integral = std::floor(temp);                                                    
    ///Euclidean algorithm , from here to
    double frac = temp - integral;
    const unsigned int precision = 1000000;                                                  
    ///possible tweak could be done here, This is the accuracy.
    unsigned int gcd_ = unsigned int(gcd(int(round(frac * precision)), 
    int(precision)));   // stackoverflow.com, user: qbt937, url: 
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643695/converting-decimal-to-
    fraction-c
    denominator = precision / gcd_;
    numerator = unsigned int(round(frac * precision) / gcd_);                              
    //here. credit for code block in middle...
    reduce();
    numerator += unsigned int((integral*denominator));
    reduce();
}

fraction::fraction(double temp)
    :fraction()
{
    if (temp < 0)
    {
        is_neg = true;
        temp *= -1;
    }
    else
    {
        is_neg = false;
    }
    double integral = std::floor(temp);                                                    
    ///Euclidean algorithm , from here to
    double frac = temp - integral;
    const unsigned int precision = 10000;                                                  
    ///possible tweak could be done here, This is the accuracy.
    unsigned int gcd_ = unsigned int(gcd(int(round(frac * precision)), 
    int(precision)));   // stackoverflow.com, user: qbt937, url: 
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643695/converting-decimal-to-
    fraction-c
    denominator = precision / gcd_;
    numerator = unsigned int(round(frac * precision) / gcd_);                              
    //here. credit for code block in middle...
    reduce();
    numerator += unsigned int((integral*denominator));
    reduce();
}

std::istream &operator >> (std::istream &is, fraction &p)
{
    std::string temp_input;
    if (char(is.peek()) == '\n')
    {
        is.ignore();
    }
    std::getline(is, temp_input);
    input_check(temp_input);
    std::istringstream temp_string(temp_input);
    char holder = ' ';
    if (temp_input[0] == '-')
    {
        p.is_neg = true;
        temp_string >> holder >> p.numerator >> holder >> p.denominator;
    }
    else
    {
        temp_string >> p.numerator >> holder >> p.denominator;
    }
    return is;
}

std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &os, fraction &p)
{
    if (p.is_neg)
    {
        os << "-" << p.numerator << "/" << p.denominator;
        return os;
    }
    else
    {
        os << p.numerator << "/" << p.denominator;
        return os;
    }
}

fraction& fraction::operator += (fraction const &two)
{
    if ((this->numerator * this->denominator) == 0)
    {
        this->numerator = two.numerator;
        this->denominator = two.denominator;
        return *this;
    }
    if ((two.numerator * two.denominator) == 0)
    {
        return *this;
    }
    bool is_it_neg = false;
    int added_num = 0;
    int common_denom = 0;
    int twonumerator = two.numerator;
    int twodenominator = two.denominator;
    if (!(this->is_neg) && !(two.is_neg))
    {
        added_num = ((this->numerator * two.denominator) + (two.numerator * 
        this->denominator));
        common_denom = (this->denominator * two.denominator);
    }
    if (this->is_neg && two.is_neg)
    {
        added_num = ((this->numerator * two.denominator) + (two.numerator * 
        this->denominator));
        common_denom = (this->denominator * two.denominator);
        is_it_neg = true;
    }
    if (this->is_neg && !(two.is_neg))
    {
        added_num = ((this->numerator * two.denominator) - (two.numerator * 
        this->denominator));
        common_denom = (this->denominator * two.denominator);
        if (added_num > 0)
        {
            is_it_neg = true;
        }
    }
    if (!(this->is_neg) && two.is_neg)
    {
        added_num = ((this->numerator * two.denominator - (two.denominator * 
        this->denominator)));
        common_denom = (this->denominator * two.denominator);
        if (added_num < 0)
        {
            added_num *= -1;
            is_it_neg = true;
        }
    }
    if(is_it_neg)
    {
        this->toggle_neg();   
    }
    this->numerator = added_num;
    this->denominator = common_denom;
    this->reduce();
    return *this;
}              

fraction operator + (fraction const &one, fraction const &two)
{
    fraction result(one);
    return (result += two);
}

fraction& fraction::operator -= (fraction const &two)
{
    int subed_num = 0;
    int common_denom = 0;
    bool is_it_neg = false;
    if ((this->numerator * this->denominator) == 0)
    {
        this->numerator = two.numerator;
        this->denominator = two.denominator;
        return *this;
    }
    if ((two.numerator * two.denominator) == 0)
    {
        return *this;
    }
    if (!(this->is_neg) && !(two.is_neg))
    {
        subed_num = ((this->numerator * two.denominator) - (two.numerator * 
        this->denominator));
        common_denom = (this->denominator * two.denominator);
        if (subed_num < 0)
        {
            subed_num *= -1;
            is_it_neg = true;
        }
    }
    if (this->is_neg && two.is_neg)
    {
        subed_num = (((this->numerator * -1) * two.denominator) + 
        (two.numerator 
        * this->denominator));
        common_denom = (this->denominator * two.denominator);
        if (subed_num < 0)
        {
            subed_num *= -1;
            is_it_neg = true;
        }
    }
    if (this->is_neg && !(two.is_neg))
    {
        subed_num = ((this->numerator * two.denominator) + (two.numerator * 
        this->denominator));
        common_denom = (this->denominator * two.denominator);
        is_it_neg = true;
    }
    if (!(this->is_neg) && two.is_neg)
    {
        subed_num = ((this->numerator * two.denominator) + (two.numerator * 
        this->denominator));
        common_denom = (this->denominator * two.denominator);
    }
    this->numerator = subed_num;
    this->denominator = common_denom;
    if (is_it_neg)
    {
        this->toggle_neg();
    }
    this->reduce();
    return *this;
}

fraction operator - (fraction one, fraction two)
{
    fraction result(one);
    return (result -= two);
}

fraction& fraction::operator *= (fraction const &two)
{
    if((this->is_neg || two.is_neg) && (!(this->is_neg) && !(two.is_neg)))
    {
        this->toggle_neg();
    }
    this->numerator = (this->numerator * two.numerator);
    this->denominator = (this->denominator * two.denominator);
    this->reduce();
    return *this;
}

fraction operator * (fraction a, fraction b)
{
    fraction result(a);
    return (result *= b);
} 

fraction& fraction::operator /= (fraction const & two)
{
    this->numerator = (this->numerator * two.denominator);
    this->denominator = (this->denominator * two.numerator);
    if ((this->is_neg || two.is_neg) && (!(this->is_neg) && !(two.is_neg)))
    {
        this->toggle_neg();
    }
    this->reduce();
    return *this;
}

fraction operator / (fraction a, fraction b)
{
    fraction result(a);
    return (result /= b);
}

bool fraction::operator == (fraction const &b) const
{
    double c = (double(this->numerator) / double(this->denominator));
    double d = (double(b.numerator) / double(b.denominator));
    if (this->is_neg)
    {
        c *= -1;
    }
    if (b.is_neg)
    {
        d *= -1;
    }
    return (c == d);
}

bool fraction::operator != (fraction const &b) const
{
    return ((*this == b) ? false : true);
}

bool fraction::operator < (fraction const &b) const
{
    double i = (double(this->numerator) / double(this->denominator));
    double j = (double(b.numerator) / double(b.denominator));
    if (this->is_neg)
    {
        i *= -1;
    }
    if (b.is_neg)
    {
        j *= -1;
    }
    return (i < j);
}

bool fraction::operator > (fraction const &b) const
{
    double k = (double(this->numerator) / double(this->denominator));
    double l = (double(b.numerator) / double(b.denominator));
    if (this->is_neg)
    {
        k *= -1;
    }
    if (b.is_neg)
    {
        l *= -1;
    }
    return (k > l);
}

bool fraction::operator <= (fraction const &b) const
{
    return ((*this < b) || (*this == b));
}

bool fraction::operator >= (fraction const &b) const
{
    return ((*this > b) || (*this == b));
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear...The gcd function was borrowed from stackoverflow.com user: qbt937. I must give credit where credit is due!

Comment: That cannot compile due to unbalanced `}`.

Comment: Something is weird about your `std::istream& operator >>` implementation. Please ensure that you have posted your code correctly. Also, this is clearly not valid [tag:c] code, so you should remove that tag.

Comment: Code edited...Sorry about that.

Comment: This is still invalid [tag:c] code, so I'm not reopening the question until you remove that tag.

Comment: It seems like in places where u do `unsigned int(expression)` it should be `(unsigned int)expression`.  Probably due to the fact that the type has spaces in it.

Comment: @200_success I believe everything is in order now, compiles on my end. c tag also removed. Sorry this is my first post, I made some mistakes.

Comment: @incomputable I believe `unsigned int(expr)` and `(unsigned int)expr` are equivalent.

Comment: @G.Foster, welp, it was giving compiler errors on godbolt on both gcc and clang, but after placing the brackets in the right places it compiled correctly. Maybe with one word types the story would be different.

Comment: @Incomputable Works on visual studios 2015, yet I better do it the way you described for the fact your compilers won't make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Re-Use of constructors

Apart from the problem Loki Astari mentioned with the user input in the constructor, your doing a lot of initialization logic multiple times and sometimes even forget some of it. For example the member `fraction_symbol` is only set in two constructors (and you don't use that one in your stream operator). You should redirect to your other constructors on only do the special initialization. Also it's better to use initializer lists than assignments:

```
fraction::fraction(int numer, int denom)
    : fraction_symbol('/')
    , is_reduced(false)
    , is_neg(false)
{
   //...
}

fraction::fraction()
    : fraction(0, 1)
{
}
```

### Simplications

No need to check `if (value) return true; else return false;` Simply return the value.

```
bool fraction::check_neg()
{
    return is_neg;
}
```

The same goes for `set_neg()`:

```
void fraction::set_neg()
{
    is_neg = !is_neg;
}
```

Also it should be renamed to something else. A `set` method implies that the user can actually define what the value is. But this method simply toggles the value.

### Keep it [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

As I said in the first section, you are repeating a lot of logic again and again. Try to reuse your previous logic in other similar code blocks. For example the comparison operator are all pretty much the same. What you really only need it the `==` and the `<` operator. All the other comparison operators can then be expressed with those too. E.g. `a != b` is the same as `!(a==b)`. The same can be used for the arithmetic operators.

### Constness

In addition to declaring member methods `const` that don't change the objects state, also take parameter inputs as `const&`.

### Surprising behaviour/Bugs

The constructors taking an `(unsigned) int` are different from the ones taking floating point values as both the nominator and denominator are set to the same value. You then reduce the fraction leading always to `1/1` no matter what input it takes. The denominator should be set to `1` instead.

The `reduce` method returns a copied `fraction` object implying that the original object is not changed. Otherwise the return type might as well be `void` or return a reference.

Why are you flushing the stream in your `<<` operator? That really hurts performance if I wanted e.g. to print many `fraction`s at the same time. Let the stream user decide when he wants to flush it.

Your `*` and `/` are wrong with respect to your `is_neg` member. If one operand is negative, the member is set to `true`. But if both operands are negative, the member should actually be `false`. Simple test case:

```
fraction f(-1.5);
fraction g(-1.5);
std::cout << f * g << '\n';
// prints -9/4 instead of 9/4
```

Comment: Greatly appreciate all the help. It means a lot.

Answer (score 4):

#### Separate of Concerns

This is a fractions class.
It has nothing to do with user input. Remove all the references to `std::cout`, and don't ask the user questions if things go wrong. Throw an exception or some other appropriate action. Then in the code that uses your class detect these situations and fix in that.

If I have a server application that is using your code I would be really pissed off if you locked up the application waiting for user input (that will never come).

#### Arithmetic

Implementing `operator+` and other operations.

This is usually done by implementing `operator+=` then defining `operator+` in terms of that:

```
 class X
 {
     public:
         X& operator+=(X const& rhs)
         {
             // Action that implements +=
             // By adding the rhs into this side.
             return *this;
         }
         friend X operator+(X const& lhs, X const& rhs)
         {
             X  result(lhs);
             return result += rhs;    // Notice the use of +=
         }
};
```

#### Questions

So the default value is 1?

```
fraction::fraction()
{
    fraction_symbol = '/';
    is_reduced = false;
    is_neg = false;
    numerator = 1;
    denominator = 1;
}
```

In most other number classes, the default value is zero.

#### Getters/Setters break encapsulation

```
    int unsigned get_numerator();
    int unsigned get_denominator();
    void set_numerator(int);
    void set_denominator(int);
```

This is a class that holds numbers more exactly. How the implementation does that should be invisible to people outside the class. In a couple of years you could find a better technique for doing this.

But because you have these functions you are basically locking yourself to this implementation, thus destroying the whole reason for encapsulating the data.

Do you really need these methods? Why would I want to get them?

#### Non mutating functions should be const

If a method does not change the state of the object it should be marked const.

```
unsigned int fraction::get_numerator()  const // Const here
{
    return numerator;
}

unsigned int fraction::get_denominator() const // Const here
{
    return denominator;
}
```